# New PSDrive and Get-Acl permission

Tags: powershell, acl

I'm making a script for users with no privileges which will allow them to create a specific folder structure and get rights on them. (read only).
The goal is to:

- create the folder structure
- `Set-Acl` read only for that user

To that end I created the following:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "target" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Credential $cred -Root $cr | Out-Null

foreach ($pers in $persons) {
    $readOnly = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"ReadAndExecute"

    # Inheritance
    $inheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"

    # Propagation
    $propagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None

    # User
    $userR = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($pers)

    # Type
    $type = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow


    $accessControlEntryR = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule @($userR, $readOnly, $inheritanceFlag, $propagationFlag, $type)
    $objACL = Get-ACL target:\$admin\$directie\$year\$dos_nr
    $objACL.AddAccessRule($accessControlEntryR)

    Set-ACL target:\$admin\$directie\$year\$dos_nr $objACL
}

Remove-PSDrive target
```

Obviously the account which I create the PSDrive with has administrator level access to that folder structure. The account which I logged on to the domain with and execute the script with (as admin in ISE) as well.

Yet I still get permission denied error.

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

exact error as requested:

> Set-Acl : Poging tot het uitvoeren van een niet-gemachtigde bewerking.
>   At line:26 char:5
>   +     Set-Acl -Path target:\$admin\$directie\$year\$dos_nr -AclObject $ ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (xxxxxxxxxx:String) [Set-Acl], UnauthorizedAccessException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand

Comment: `SetAccessRule()` replaces existing ACEs. Are you looking for `AddAccessRule()`? What permissions do you expect after the operation, and what permissions do you actually get? Does the error occur in your code or when a user tries to access the folder? Also, please show the full, unaltered error message. Do not paraphrase.

Comment: permissions after operation: everything inherited from folders above needs to stay, i only want to add 1 (or multiple if needed) new users with only read rights. Will update original post with error and current code